# Concurrent UART Output with Line Buffered

Tags: linux, concurrency, grep, cat

I have 4 UART devices and I want to watch their output concurrently. I use the following script to do this job:

```
# first kill the cat process from last run
killall -v cat

for i in `seq 0 3`; do
    cat /dev/crbif0rb0c$(i}ttyS0 | grep . --line-buffered &
    # cat /dev/crbif0rb0c$(i)ttyS0 &
done
```

But I get no output from this script, except many empty lines. When I remove the `grep` stuff and use the second line in the for loop, I get a lot of outputs, but not readable since all outputs are messed up.

So my question is **why there is no output (except empty lines) when I use grep**? Or anyone can provide a better (and workable) solutions for my scenario?

Thanks in advance!

**[UPDATE]** I suddenly found that `cat /dev/crbif0rb0c${i}ttyS0 | grep ^ --line-buffered &` will work. Don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

How about `tail -f /dev/crbif0rb0c{0,1,2,3}` ?

Comment: Are your UARTs printing CR and/or LFs? Because the output won't be printed until they've finished a line.

Comment: They are printing "\n". But never mind, problem solved by replace the `.` by `^` in `grep`.